# Setting the value of two number pickers to the hours and minutes of a countdown timer

Tags: java, android, timer

I currently have two number pickers. One to set the value of hours, and one to set the value of minutes for a countdown timer. Right now whats happening is the value of the countdown timer either the value of the hours number picker or the minutes number picker, but never both which is what it should be. So my question is how can I change the textView of the countdown timer to both the hours and minute number picker value. This might be kinda confusing to understand if you have questions ask. 
Here is my code...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
NumberPicker noPickerHours;
NumberPicker noPickerMinutes;
TextView textViewTime;
Button button;
CounterClass timer;
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    textViewTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    noPickerMinutes = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
    noPickerMinutes.setMaxValue(59);
    noPickerMinutes.setMinValue(0);
    noPickerHours = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    noPickerHours.setMaxValue(24);
    noPickerHours.setMinValue(0);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);



    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            timer.start();
        }
    });

    noPickerHours.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            timer = new CounterClass((newVal * 60 * 1000), 1000);
            long millis = (newVal * 60 * 1000);
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            textViewTime.setText(hms);
        }
    });

    noPickerMinutes.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {


        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            timer = new CounterClass((newVal * 60 * 1000), 1000);
            long millis = (newVal * 60 * 1000);
            String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
            textViewTime.setText(hms);
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}



public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {


    /**
     * @param millisInFuture    The number of millis in the future from the call
     *                          to {@link #start()} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
     *                          is called.
     * @param countDownInterval The interval along the way to receive
     *                          {@link #onTick(long)} callbacks.
     */

    public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }



    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long millis = millisUntilFinished;
        String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
        System.out.println(hms);
        textViewTime.setText(hms);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {

    }


}}
```

Comment: If anyone has any thoughts just comment. Anything helps

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that in both `NumberPicker` objects, `noPickerHours` and `noPickerMinutes` when the values are changed, the `setOnValueChangedListener()` method gets called . If you change `noPickerHours`  picker, then the timer is set to the hour and if `noPickerMinutes` picker is changed then the timer is set to the minute specified. So the last number picker which you changed will be the value of timer.

So the solution will be:

```
int hourPicked;
int minPicked;  // declare both as instance variables otherwise will need to declare as final variables.

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // put your logic here to set the time with hourPicked and minPicked variables.
        timer.start();
    }
});

noPickerHours.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {


    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
       hourPicked = newVal;   
    }
});

noPickerMinutes.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {


    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
         minPicked = newVal;  
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Im sorry im kind of new to java what would that logic look like in the onClick method.